# Mule is inserting space in path for re-routing

Tags: java, mule, mule-component

I am deploying more than one application in a container and having one top level for rerouting. Using this one to give the path to next application 
`#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path']"`.

The problem is in the next level of application I am seeing this:

```
/%20/v1/users/123456789/employee
```

How can I remove this space either in top level application or next one?

Comment: And its adding one more slash in starting like "//v1/users/..."

Comment: Please paste your Mule configuration XML. Maybe there is a redundant "/" or extra space somewhere in config or HTTP request component.

Answer (score 0):

had to use message.inboundProperties.'http.relative.path'